# Pivot without aggregate on numeric field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which produces the result like:

```
Code   Month    Value

733     May      520.00
733     May     2250.00
733     May      125.00
```

I have a requirement where I need to display above records like this:

```
Code    May
733      520
733     2250
733      125
```

I can think of one way by going for **pivot** so I was going like:

```
Select 
    Code,
    IsNull(January,0)[January(Actual)],          
    IsNull(February,0)[February(Actual)],              
    IsNull(March,0)[March(Actual)],              
    IsNull(April,0)[April(Actual)],              
    IsNull(May,0)[May(Actual)],              
    IsNull(June,0)[June(Actual)],              
    IsNull(July,0)[July(Actual)],              
    IsNull(August,0)[August(Actual)],              
    IsNull(September,0)[September(Actual)],              
    IsNull(October,0)[October(Actual)],              
    IsNull(November,0)[November(Actual)],              
    IsNull(December,0)[December(Actual)]
From 
    (
    Select 
         Code,
         [Month],
         Value
    From 
        #tempMonthWiseActualValue
    )s 
Pivot  
    (
         min([Value] )
         For [Month]           
        In    (January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December) 
    )as pvt
Order by Code
```

But there is one restriction since I need to keep all the values so no aggregate function will work here i.e. no MIN, MAX,SUM etc. And using Min/Max will give me either 125 or 2250 in     value column.

So my question is :

Is there a way through which I can find desired result by using pivot table or Should I go for #temp tables ?

Comment: Let's say you have 2 rows in May and 2 in April for the same code: `1,May,10`; `1,May,20`; `1,Apr,30`; `1,Apr,40`. How computer should tell if output you want should be: `1,10 as May, 30 as Apr` or `1,10 as May, 40 as Apr`?

Comment: What happens when there are values for other months? Or more for the same month? Do you create a new row for each Original entry?

Comment: Since values of months are related to Code it doesn't matter how they are appearing in the result. For the final result it can be 1,10 as May, 30 as Apr or 1,10 as May, 40 as Apr.

Comment: SQL Server does not understand and cannot process `does not matter` command. You should tell exactly what to do. Query on same data should produce same result every time. What if one month has more data then another? It looks like you'll need 11 `OUTER JOIN`s...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is a very narrow workaround. It serves purpose to hightlight problems of putting data on same row from different months.
If you describe the ovarall task, then I can suggest better solution.

```
Select 
  Code as Code
  Value as May
from Table
where Month = 'May'
```

Comment: Thanks for your query I found it working but again a question. How can we expand it for multiple months ? I think I need to use select case statement in that case Or not ?

Comment: 11 `OUTER JOIN`s - if you'll be doing it this way. This is why we need more information about overall task.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario use of Row_number() will allow to get the desired output and it will also handle even if there are multiple months and one month has more values than other. Hope it helps someone facing similar situation:

```
Select  
    Code,
    rnum,
    IsNull(January,0)[January(Value)],          
    IsNull(February,0)[February(Value)],              
    IsNull(March,0)[March(Value)],              
    IsNull(April,0)[April(Value)],              
    IsNull(May,0)[May(Value)],              
    IsNull(June,0)[June(Value)],              
    IsNull(July,0)[July(Value)],              
    IsNull(August,0)[August(Value)],              
    IsNull(September,0)[September(Value)],              
    IsNull(October,0)[October(Value)],              
    IsNull(November,0)[November(Value)],              
    IsNull(December,0)[December(Value)]

From 
    (
    Select 
         Code,
        ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by nSRNo) [rnum],
        [Month],
        Value
    From 
        #tempMonthWiseActualValue
    )s 
Pivot 
    (
     Max([Value] )
     For [Month]           
     In (January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December) 
)as pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this

Firstly, Using simple case :)

```
SELECT 
Code AS Code,
CASE WHEN Month = 'January' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS January ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'February' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS February ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'March' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS March ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'April' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS April ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'May' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS May ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'June' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS June ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'July' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS July ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'August' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS August ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'September' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS September ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'October' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS October ,
CASE WHEN Month = 'November' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS November, 
CASE WHEN Month = 'December' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS December 
FROM CodePivot1
```

Secondly, Using Pivot and Rownum

```
SELECT Code,
ISNULL(January,0) AS January,
ISNULL(February,0) AS February,
ISNULL(March,0) AS March,
ISNULL(April,0) AS April,
ISNULL(May,0) AS May,
ISNULL(June,0) AS June,
ISNULL(July,0) AS July,
ISNULL(August,0) AS August,
ISNULL(September,0) AS September,
ISNULL(October,0) AS October,
ISNULL(November,0) AS November,
ISNULL(December,0) AS December  
FROM  
    (
    SELECT 
         Code, [Month],  Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code) [rnum]
    FROM 
        CodePivot1
    )s 
PIVOT 
    (
     MAX([Value])
     FOR [Month]           
     IN (January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December) 
)as p
```